# Getting Push Notification in android using sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite, push-notification, titanium

How do I get a message as a push notification at 8:00 AM in Android using titanium? The message is already stored in a SQLite database.

Comment: can you please explain what you want...?

Comment: Are you talking about `Local Notification` ?

Comment: @ Krunal Indrodiya Actually, i have several massage in my db and i want single massage sequentially everyday in a particular time as a push notification.

Comment: @Simple Plan Yes i want Local notification.

Comment: This link may help you.  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this module to get local notification.

https://github.com/benbahrenburg/benCoding.AlarmManager

Answer (score 0):

get your message from db and notify

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
 import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    showNotification("This is My Text");

}
private void showNotification(String message) {
    // In this sample, we'll use the same text for the ticker and the expanded notification
    CharSequence text =message;

    // Set the icon, scrolling text and timestamp
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, text,
            System.currentTimeMillis());

    // The PendingIntent to launch our activity if the user selects this notification
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);
    //  PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),0,
    //      new Intent(),PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    // Set the info for the views that show in the notification panel.
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, message,
                   text, contentIntent);
     NotificationManager mNM;
     mNM = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
     int NOTIFICATION = 0;
     // Send the notification.
    mNM.notify(NOTIFICATION, notification);
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
 }

}
```